# How to count and get a list of specified value in dart and flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following UML class diagram:
[UML class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJKvh.png)

I want to display a list view of all featured products found in each company.
I expect to get only **featured products**:

- product 00 (from company abc)
- product 02 (from company abc)
- product 11 (from company xyz)

*but the below code give me only the first item **product 00**.*

I tried to counts the **featured products**
but the length always 1.

```
List<Product> temps;
    for (var i = 0; i < companies.length; i++) {
      
      temps = companies[i]
          .products
          .where((fp) => fp.isFeatured == true)
          .toList();
    }
    print('===> ${temps.length}'); // <----- here
```

This is the model **Dart** code with the data:

```
class Product {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final double price;
  final bool isFeatured;

  Product({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.price,
    this.isFeatured,
  });
}

class Company {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final List<Product> products;

  Company({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.products,
  });
}

List<Product> productsOfCompanyAbc = [
  Product(
    id: 0,
    name: 'product 00',
    price: 10.0,
    isFeatured: true,
  ),
  Product(
    id: 1,
    name: 'product 01',
    price: 20.0,
    isFeatured: false,
  ),
  Product(
    id: 2,
    name: 'product 02',
    price: 25.0,
    isFeatured: true,
  ),
];

List<Product> productsOfCompanyXyz = [
  Product(
    id: 0,
    name: 'product 11',
    price: 30.0,
    isFeatured: true,
  ),
  Product(
    id: 1,
    name: 'product 12',
    price: 40.0,
    isFeatured: false,
  ),
];

List<Company> companies = [
  Company(
    id: 0,
    name: 'Company abc',
    products: productsOfCompanyAbc,
  ),
  Company(
    id: 1,
    name: 'Company xyz',
    products: productsOfCompanyXyz,
  )
];
```

This is the **Flutter** sample:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  int countFeaturedProducts() {
    List<Product> temps;
    for (var i = 0; i < companies.length; i++) {
      
      temps = companies[i]
          .products
          .where((fp) => fp.isFeatured == true)
          .toList();
      // this product TRUE items that is featured
      for (var item in temps) {
        print(item.name);
       
      }
    }
    print('===> ${temps.length}');
    print('===> out');
    return temps.length;
  }


List<Product> featuredProducts(int index){
    List<Product> allFeatured;
    for (var i = 0; i < companies[index].products.length; i++) {
      allFeatured = companies[index].products;
    }
    return allFeatured;
  }
    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.blueGrey,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: countFeaturedProducts(), //<------- Here give length 1.
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(featuredProducts(index)[index].name), //<------- Here give only one Product 00.
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
temps = companies[i]
          .products
          .where((fp) => fp.isFeatured == true)
          .toList();
```

replaces `temps` over every loop. It sounds like you want to append featured items to an aggregated list. So you want something like this:

```
temps.addAll(companies[i]
          .products
          .where((fp) => fp.isFeatured == true)
          .toList());
```

but using that directly will fail because `temps` isn't initialized, so you need to initialize it with something like this:

```
List<Product> temps = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < companies.length; i++) {
      
      temps.addAll(companies[i]
          .products
          .where((fp) => fp.isFeatured == true));
    }
    print('===> ${temps.length}'); // <----- here
```

However, rather than looping, an easier way could be using the [`expand`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/expand.html) function:

```
List<Product> temps = companies.expand((company) => company.products.where((product) => product.isFeatured)).toList();
print('===> ${temps.length}'); // <----- here
```

Comment: It give the following error: `NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'addAll'`

Comment: @fromearth I updated my answer along with a new way to do it which may be easier. If this solves your issue, please accept it.